# Скрипт отправки данных на e-mail не работает на хостингах

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть готовый скрипт отправки формы на e-mail, проблема в том, что на одном платном хостинге net.ru с php и mysql он не работает(или работает, но сообщения приходят в спам через час), а на другом платном хостинге agava он работает как надо, сообщение приходит мнгновенно во входящие, в чем может быть проблема, для отправки сообщений используется ф-ия mail

Comment: вы почтовик на хосте настраивали?

Answer (score 3):

Если на одном хостинге работает, а на другом - нет, то проблема, однозначно, в хостинге.

Во-первых, функция отправки почты может быть банально выключена. А может быть не просто выключена, а хитро - MTA берёт почту от скрипта и выкидывает её в `/dev/null`. Ошибок нет, но и почты нет.

Во-вторых, при наличии большого числа клиентов на хостинге он весь, либо некоторая часть его IP-адресов может попасть в чёрный список из-за спама. Тогда возможен и "отброс" почты принимающей стороной, и попадание в спам.

В третьих, возможно, хостер не прописал Reverse DNS или криво настроил MTA. В таких случаях принимающая строна может сказать отправителю "повтори отправку через час". Легитимные почтовики честно повторят отправку, в то время как спамеры не станут заморачиваться и просто пройдут мимо. Это объясняет задержку на час.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, а какой хостинг дешевый можете посоветовать с работающей функцией mail, форма отправки работает на ajax, нужно просто, чтобы на обычном html сайте была форма обратной связи спасибо

Comment: По-моему, Beget и Timeweb достаточно дешёвые и `mail` работает. Но не уверен. У них есть бесплатный тестовый период. Потестируйте вначале.

Comment: проверил сейчас на хостинге beget.ru, все письма приходят мнгновенно, но попадают в спам, как сделать, чтобы они во входящие попадали, спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку для работы с почтой на PHP, например Swiftmailer - эта библиотека может отправлять почту через функцию mail. Вот пример создания и отправки сообщения http://ideone.com/AQHqWm

Comment: @maksvolf Это вопрос к принимающему почтовому серверу. Только он знает, почему эти письма расцениваются как спам. Скорее всего, стоит байесов фильтр и ему не нравится текст.